# Android: Managing Multiple Notifications

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create multiple notifications in my application. To identify each notification uniquely, i have given them an unique identificationId. Following is my code:

```
private void updateNotification(int notificationId, int clockStatusID, CharSequence text) {
 //notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
// throws up an ongoing notification that the timer is running
Log.i("TIMERCOUNT", "Notification id: " + notificationId);
Notification not = new Notification(clockStatusID, // the
    // icon
    // for
    // the
    // status
    // bar
    text, // the text to display in the ticker
    System.currentTimeMillis() // the timestamp for the
    // notification to appear
);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("notificationID", notificationId);
intent.setAction("actionstring" + System.currentTimeMillis());
intent.setClassName("com.chander.time.android.activities",
"com.chander.time.android.activities.Tabs");


not.setLatestEventInfo(self,
    getText(R.string.timer_notification_title),
    getText(R.string.timer_on_notification_text), PendingIntent
    .getActivity(this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

not.flags += Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
not.flags += Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, not);
}
```

Problem:
When a notification is selected, Tabs activity is called passing the intent. I want to access the unique notificationId of the notification that was selected in Tabs. I tried intent.putExtra() to save the notificationId in the intent. But, for multiple notifications its overwriting the notificationId and returns the latest one. I dont understand as to why this is happening and how can i avoid this overwriting of notificationId.

Thanks,
Chander

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the answer. The intents were getting cached in. To, make a new intent, just add the following piece of code:

```
saveCallIntent.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"+System.currentTimeMillis())));
```

This makes the intent unique.

Also, someone suggested me the following piece of code to make the intent unique:

```
saveCallIntent.setAction("actionstring" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

It didnt help me, but might be of help to someone else.

--Chander

Answer (score 7):

just place the `notificationId` instead of 0 in `pendingIntent`.

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationId, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

The user must also update the following code together with the above one to get it working.

```
 mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
```