# Show multiple notifications on receiving gcm notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am showing notification at the notification bar like this. I am getting those , but I cant show multiple notifications there,only one at a time. When a new one comes , previous one go. What shall be the problem?

```
 public void createNotificationRecever(Context context, String payload) {
        Toast.makeText(context, commentor  +  "commented on your post "   ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //New message received
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.flag,
                payload, System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageReceivedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", groupid);
        intent.putExtra("userid", text);
        intent.putExtra("cname", groupname);
        intent.putExtra("image", "");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Message",
                payload, pendingIntent);         
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);


    }}
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how many Notifications you need there are several solutions. You could add an id that increments to your notification so it would have a different name and therefor wont replace the other one with the same id or if you need only two notifications max then just create a second notification with different names of the strings/variables you are using.

Have a look here for the ID increment:

[Android: Managing Multiple Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465230/android-managing-multiple-notifications)

If you just need a second or third notification change your strings to something like this for example:

```
public void createNotificationRecever(Context context2, String payload2) {
    Toast.makeText(context2, commentor  +  "commented on your post "   ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //New message received
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context2
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification2 = new Notification(R.drawable.flag,
            payload2, System.currentTimeMillis());
    // Hide the notification after its selected
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Intent intent = new Intent(context2, MessageReceivedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", groupid2);
    intent.putExtra("userid", text2);
    intent.putExtra("cname", groupname2);
    intent.putExtra("image", "");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Message",
            payload, pendingIntent);         
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification2);


}}
```

I hope you get the gist and that it helps you.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code it will bring multiple notifications in list
int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
`notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification2);
NOTIFICATION_ID++`

Answer (score 0):

@SunnySonic, You need to use the latest stable release of "Android Support Library".

To download the latest stable release of "Android Support Libraray",
Goto SDK Manager -> Extras - > click on Android Support Library and update it.

and goto build.gradle and under "dependencies", change the version.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'  //<-change this
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random number as NotificationId in notify method.

notificationManager.notify(generateRandom(), notificationBuilder.build());

```
public int generateRandom()
{
    Random rn = new Random();
    int n = maximum - minimum + 1;
    int i = rn.nextInt() % n;
    return  minimum + i;

}
```